# Producing more functional dependencies (FDs) from a list of functional dependencies (FDs)

Tags: db.databases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Producing more functional dependencies (FDs) from a list of functional dependencies (FDs)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6517/producing-more-functional-dependencies-fds-from-a-list-of-functional-dependenci)

I am currently trying to understand functional dependencies and their properties. I am looking at an example, but when I try to apply the rules I can't see to get the same answers. The question is:

> Question: Given a relation T(A,B, C,D)
>   and functional dependencies AB -> C,
>   BC -> D,CD -> A AD -> B What FD’s
>   follow from the given FD’s?
>
> Answer: AD -> CD,AD -> BC,CD -> AB.

When applying the properties of functional dependencies I can't even see how they get the first answer (AD -> CD). If anyone could give me an idea of how we get to the first answer, maybe I can solve the rest myself.

PS: This is NOT homework (as I already have the answer!), but I am revising for an important exam and I need to understand these concepts.

Thanks!

Comment: The thread was closed because someone thought it was homework, when I've made it clear that it is NOT homework because I already have the answers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of posting a new duplicated question, here we usually discuss the scope of the original one in [meta](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/), and see if there are agreements on reopening it. And this site is for research-level questions in theoretical computer science, normally not included undergrad course materials, whether they are homework or not.

Comment: cstheory is for research level questions in theoretical computer science. As you mentioned, this is an undergraduate level question, and thus out of scope. I recommend sites like http://math.stackexchange.com/ for undergraduate level questions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I didn't realise cstheory was only for research-level questions. Please feel free to help me nonetheless.